# sorting a list which is provided from users in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking input from uses as a list and then try to make it sort using sort() function . But every time I got an error which I can't understand what to do . Can anyone help me here to come over of that error ?

I'm done it on Pycharm which is based on Python3.7 but while using sort() function I got an error everytime .

```
a=input("give your list to be sorted : ")
a.split()
a.sort()
print(a)
```

```
give your list to be sorted : 3 2 44 5 6 99 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ................................................................., line 3, in <module>
    a.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `a.split()` **returns** a list. You have to capture the return value.

Answer (score 0):

`a.split()` doesn't modify the string itself, it returns a new object.

use `a = a.split()` to override the previous `a` with the new list.

also - it will be a  list of string and will sort lexicographicaly, to sort it by numeric value please try:

```py
a = input("give your list to be sorted : ").split()
a.sort(key=int)
print(a)
```

Comment: so what to do now can u suggest anything ?

Comment: @AnimeshBanerjee I edited my answer, with a complete example